# Auto refresh in partial view doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

The "Refresh Now" button works but the "Auto Refresh" doesn't.

```
 <br /><br />
            <a id="button" title="Refresh now">Refresh Now</a>
        <a id="toggleButton" title="Auto refresh every 5 seconds">Auto Refresh</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoRefresh = false;
    var autoRefreshInterval = 1000 * 5;
```

This is the "Refresh Now" function. It works like a refresh button.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#button').click(function () {
            $('#PartialDiv').load('@Url.Action("RefreshLiveContent", "ThreadClass", new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClassThreadID })');  //, new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClass}
        });
```

This is the Auto Refresh Function

```
        $('a#toggleButton').click(function () {
            $('#PartialDiv').Load('@Url.Action("RefreshLiveContent", "ThreadClass", new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClassThreadID })');  //, new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClass}
            $(this).toggleClass("down");
            if ($(this).is('.down')) {
                autoRefresh = true;
            } else {
                autoRefresh = false;
            }
        });

        var refresh = function () {
            if (autoRefresh) {
                $('#PartialDiv').Load('@Url.Action("RefreshLiveContent", "ThreadClass", new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClassThreadID })'); //new { id = (int)ViewBag.SelectedThreadClass}
            }
            setTimeout(refresh, autoRefreshInterval);
        };

        refresh();

    });
</script>


<fieldset>
    <legend>Test Live Content</legend>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="PartialDiv">
        @Html.Partial("LiveContent",Model)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The error I got is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: Btw this is in the Index page

Comment: what line of code is this error happening on?

Comment: It's at the auto refresh funtion. Right before the var refresh= function()

Comment: you see the typo in .Load()  try .load()

Comment: let me know if that works , I'll put it in an answer

Comment: please accept the answer and upvote it if it helped, I put it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there  is a typo in the load function?

```
  $('#PartialDiv').Load('@Url.Action("Ref
```

should be changed to

```
   $('#PartialDiv').load('@Url.Action("Ref
```